# SQL difference in item from one week to another

Tags: mysql, sql

Teams table

```
+------+------------+
|team_id |    week    |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 2012-09-10 |
|    2 | 2012-09-10 |
|    3 | 2012-09-17 |
|    4 | 2012-09-17 |
+------+------------+
```

TeamPlayers Join Table

```
+---------+-----------+
| team_id | player_id |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |         1 |
|       2 |         2 |
|       3 |         1 |
|       4 |         1 |
+---------+-----------+
```

Based on the schema above I need to put a query together that will show me which player was added and which player was dropped between this week and last week.

For example

Between week 2012-09-10 and 2012-1=09-17 Player 8 was moved on successfully (he appeared on one team last week and 2 teams this week).
Player 9 appeared on a team last week 2012-09-10 but did not make it to this week 2012-09-17.

I am currently doing this in the application code (because I am not a sql expert), but have a nagging feeling that there is likely a way to perform this directly in the database
(mysql).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm still not quite understanding the semantics of the tables. Is "Players" the total number of players on a Team, or is that a player number? Or are we saying that a given Player may appear on multiple Teams? As I said, still not quite understanding things...any clarification would be great.

Comment: Thanks for the response David. The information is all ids.  I modified the table to reflect.

Comment: Do you have a table that stores the per-team rosters on a per-week basis? That is, a table that would have the fields TEAM_ID, WEEK, PLAYER_ID? Because if the TEAMPLAYERS table reflects the current status of the team it'll be harder (if not impossible) to know the state of the team(s) in detail on a prior week.

Comment: I don't have that. What I am doing in the application at the moment is building a Hash with the data you mentioned above. One hash for this week and another hash for last week and then processing them to see the difference.

Comment: Just fired off a request to change the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start, may need some tweeking. hope it helps.

```
SELECT * FROM teams t
INTO #TMP
INNER JOIN teamsplayers tp ON tp.team_id = t.team_id
;

SELECT count(*), week, player_id
FROM #TMP
GROUP BY week, player_id
ORDER BY week, player_id
;
```

> ```
> Edit:
> ```
>
> DROP TABLE #TMP;

Comment: Thanks, will give this a shot and provide feedback.